# How to add Token to a model that extends the User Model in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I have the following to create a user and add a Token to it:

```
User = get_user_model()

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email') 
        extra_kwargs = {'passwords': {'write_only': True, 'required': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        token = Token.objects.create(user=user)
        return user
```

I would like to be able to do the same thing for a Player:

```
class PlayerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # what to do here? How to create a new token for 'Player'?
```

I've tried this:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    player = Player.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
    token = Token.objects.create(user=player)
    return player
```

But got this error: `TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use groups.set() instead.`

The Player model extends the 'MyUser' model:

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Player(MyUser):
    national_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.username = self.email
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't point anything to the referenced error. What was the JSON payload that you have sent? Show complete error traceback

Comment: It seems your data models is not correct. You need to updated the question with more clear information.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using a payload similar to this:

```
{
    "username": "root",
    "password": "test",
    "first_name": "a",
    "last_name": "b",
    "email": "a@b.com",
    "national_id": "123",
}
```

Django's **`AbstractUser`** comes with several fields not included in this payload (eg. `is_staff`, `is_superuser`), most of which come with either default arguments, or are allowed to be null.

Because you specified `fields = '__all__'` in your **`PlayerSerializer`**, your endpoint is expecting **every field** to be present in the payload, hence your error.

If you were using a traditional model setup (by that I mean no inheritance), you would have received a helpful error message telling you exactly what's missing.  I suspect the model inheritance aspect part of your code broke the serializer early, resulting in an unhelpful message.

Anyways, if my assumption is correct, you can fix this in 2 ways:

- include **all** of **`AbstractUser`**'s fields in your payload; see the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/f1f24539d8c86f60d1e2951a19eb3178e15d6399/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L321) for a full list
- modify your serializer's meta to specify the fields you want.

eg:

```
class PlayerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = (
            'username',
            'password',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'national_id',
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        player = Player.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        token = Token.objects.create(user=player)
        return player
```

Comment: Can you tell us what was the reason behind the error, specified in OP? or how can I reproduce the *"`TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use groups.set() instead.`"* exception?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu using the payload in my answer, with OP's code (after migrations, and disabling auth), you can see it via `import requests; requests.post('http:localhost:8000', data=payload)` assuming you created a view and linked it to `/`

Comment: @ArakkalAbu as for the first part of your comment, I don't know, but I was able to fix the problem by specifying only the required fields in meta.